# Date time format when application runs as windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, datetime-format

In my system the date format is set as `YYY-MM-DD` format.So my c# application will take this format when i call `DateTime.Now` which is fine.

Now in installed my application as service using Install util command.

After running services it gets the date format as `dd/mm/yyy`.
But i want to save the format as `yyy-MM-DD` format in database.

Whether i need to change my code or i can set this format in system.

because already the regional settings are done in `yyy-mm-dd` format only.

This problem happens only when I install my application as a service.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean `yyyy` not `yyy`, don't you?

Comment: @abatishchev This is the same for our era: according to msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) : `yyy` = _The year in three digits. If the year is less than 100, the year is displayed with a leading zero._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DateTime formatting:

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd");
```

That will get you:

> `yyy`: The year (same as `yyyy`), e.g. `2011`
>   `MM`: The month number (single digit is formatted with leading zero)
>   `dd`: The day number (single digit is formatted with leading zero)

Answer (score 3):

First a question to you: why do you store the date as a string in your database? I would strongly suggest to store it as a date value instead. This would eliminate any formatting problems when storing data.

As a second suggestion, I would make sure to format the string explicitly, rather than relying on system settings, if you need to store it in a specific format:

```
var dateAsString = theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: and use the globalization features: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> In my system the date format is set as YYY-MM-DD format

In Regional Settings?

That only sets the format for the current user. Hence has no effect on processes running as another user as service processes nearly always do.